# Intuitive way to look at Matrix addition

Tags: matrices

There's a model for multiplication, but is there any visual meaning for adding two matrices together, while thinking of them as vectors or functions?

Comment: matrices are just  short hand notation, write them out and it is all obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be matrices. If you want to interpret them as functions $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ that takes $x$ to $Ax$ and $Bx$, respectively, then you can interpret $A + B$ as another function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ which takes $x$ to $Ax + Bx$.